# WPF thumb . Cannot get rid of focus style

Tags: wpf, .net-3.5

Here is the style of a thumb that i created...(triangle) . 
Although i got rid of mouseover style etc, i cant get rid of focus no matter what i do...

I created a polygon in order to create the triangle...
I use that thumb within a slider control

```
  <Style x:Key="HorizontalSliderThumbStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
                <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="false"/>
                <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
                <Setter Property="Height" Value="22"/>
                <Setter Property="Width" Value="11"/>
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Gray"/>
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
                            <Canvas SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                                <Canvas.RenderTransform>
                                    <TranslateTransform X="5.5" Y="11"/>
                                </Canvas.RenderTransform>                           
                                <Path x:Name="InnerBorder" Stroke="White"/>
                                <Path x:Name="OuterBorder" Stroke="#FF929292"/>
                                <Polygon  FocusVisualStyle="{x:Null}"  x:Name="Background"   Points="0,0 1,0 0.5,1"    Fill="#FFF18200"  Width="15.3"  Height="15"  Stretch="Fill"   Canvas.Left="-7.5" Canvas.Top="-8" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" />
                            </Canvas>
                            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                                <!--    <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="Background" Value="{StaticResource HorizontalSliderThumbHoverBackground}"/>
                                    <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="OuterBorder" Value="{StaticResource HorizontalSliderThumbHoverBorder}"/>-->
                                </Trigger>
                                <Trigger Property="Foreground" Value="Blue">
                                    <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="Background" Value="{StaticResource HorizontalSliderThumbHoverBackground}"/>
                                    <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="OuterBorder" Value="{StaticResource HorizontalSliderThumbHoverBorder}"/>
                                </Trigger>
                                <Trigger Property="IsDragging" Value="true">
                                <!--    <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="Background" Value="{StaticResource HorizontalSliderThumbPressedBackground}"/>
                                    <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="OuterBorder" Value="{StaticResource HorizontalSliderThumbPressedBorder}"/>-->
                                </Trigger>
                                <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                                    <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="Background" Value="#FFF4F4F4"/>
                                    <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="InnerBorder" Value="{x:Null}"/>
                                    <Setter Property="Data" TargetName="OuterBorder" Value="{StaticResource SliderThumbDisabledGeometry}"/>
                                    <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="OuterBorder" Value="#FFAEB1AF"/>
                                </Trigger>
                            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <Trigger Property="Foreground" Value="Blue">
                                    <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="Background" Value="{StaticResource HorizontalSliderThumbHoverBackground}"/>
                                    <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="OuterBorder" Value="{StaticResource HorizontalSliderThumbHoverBorder}"/>


         </Trigger>
```

Oh god this property did the problem.. I think that this is really strange.. Blue means nothing to me...Dont know why microsoft did this..

Answer (score 0):

Set the FocusVisualStyle on your Thumb Style to null.